How do I calculate the $B$ field of a solenoid while taking into account saturation?
I know that the $B$ field of a solenoid is $N\frac{\mu_0 \mu_r
 I}{\ell}$.
But if saturation is, for instance, 1.6 T, would the formula have to take this into account, when calculating B?

the permeability coefficient $\mu_r$ is meaningful only in the linear or almost linear regime, and certainly not in saturation.

The equation for static magnetic fields starts from the equation,
\begin{equation*}
\text{rot}{\mathbf H}={\mathbf J}, \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where $H$ is magnetic-H field or magnetic field.
This equation always holds for static magnetic fields, including when the magnetisation is saturated.
In the problem of infinite length solenoid coils,
this equation yields the solution
\begin{equation*}
H=NI/l \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
In other words, $H$ remains the same whether saturated or not.
If $H$ is small, calculate $B$ from the equation,
\begin{equation*}
B=\mu_0\mu_rH. \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
$\mu_r$ is constant, and experimentally it is about 1000 or 1500.
If $H$ is large enough to achieve saturation, calculate $B$ from the approximate equation,
\begin{equation*}
B=\mu_0\mu_r^{\prime}H+M_0, \tag{4}
\end{equation*}
where, in your case, $M_0=1.6(T)$, which is constant magnetization.
If I remember correctly, $\mu_r^{\prime}$ is a constant greater than 1 but close to 1.
